# What is the difference in defining Page Objects with GET vs VALUE in Protractor?

Tags: javascript, protractor, pageobjects

I have seen two ways of defining functions/objects when reviewing javascript in Protractor:

One looks like this:

```
name1: { get: function() { return element.all(by.css('.mything')); }},
```

Another looks like this:

```
name2: { value: function() { return element.all(by.css('.files')); }}
```

Can someone please explain what the difference is between the use of VALUE vs GET with defining Page Objects?

Comment: it's just the functions name, i wouldn't bother. maybe programmers with Java background prever `get` and others prever `value` ... who knows ;o

Comment: This looks like an Astrolabe question. Personally I don't wrap ElementFinders in functions since is [not necessary](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/page-objects.md#with-pageobjects)

Comment: Here is a great article explaining the differences.

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/object.create-the-new-way-to-create-objects-in-javascript.html